# Array to string conversion in......array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to get the average of a column in a table,

table: buy
column: c1

when I called the database
with this:

```html
$query="Select AVG(c1) as average FROM buy";
$result_array=mysql_query($query);
$line = mysql_fetch_array($result_array);
```

and when I called with `php` like this

```html
<?php echo $line; ?>
```

it came up error with this message

**Array to string conversion in .......... on line 50
Array**

what did I do wrong? I think because I treated arrays as a string. but how can i fix this?

Comment: `<?php echo "<pre/>";print_r( $line); ?>` or `<?php var_dump( $line); ?>`or `<?php print( $line); ?>` and stop using `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and have major security holes.

Comment: RTM: [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php): _Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row..._, you can't `echo` an `array`.

Comment: Please, take a look at [**Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4577762)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look that $line returns an array. So, you can't echo an array. One thing you can do is

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($line);
```

Check what the array looks like.

Is it a single row that's been returned? In that case you can write

```
echo $line['average'];
```

If it's more than one row:

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result_array)) {
   echo $line['average'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: wow!!!  i use: echo $line['average']; and it's working!!! thank you:)) you're a master